# Spring framework self-training

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'd like to learn Spring MVC framework basis.
My personal experience tells clearly that more than reading manuals, docs, howtos only is *only one important part* of self-training, but to capitalize **real** experience you need to solve **real** problems.
May someone suggest a fake-project that I can implement in my free-time, avoiding only-theoretical approaches and at the same time watch at the main issues of Spring programming? 
Does a [NerdDinner.com-like](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) free-chapter somewhere exists for Spring?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284425/what-are-ten-really-good-short-programs-you-can-write-to-help-become-fluent-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go through each of the [Spring samples](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/), and attempt to recreate them on your own.

I have found that a very effective method for learning Spring is to go on the [Spring JIRA](https://jira.springframework.org/) and solve a bug.  It forces you to get down and dirty in the code, and you get to see what's really going on behind the scenes.